# What is better: a single class with some attributes unfilled or multiple classes with attributes filled?

Tags: java, class

I have a class called Page in my program. It has 10 attributes, but at certain point, only 3 attributes are needed (RawPage) and in other point, all or almost all atributes are needed (ProcessedPage).

Is better I have  only only one class with all attributes or split these class into two classes, one for every need?

**EDIT:** the processed atributes are new attributes in the Page, and not overwrites none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect someone will suggest using inheritance here, but I won't... it sounds like you logically *create* a "processed page" from a "raw page" (via processing) - so why not model it exactly like that?

```
class ProcessedPage
{
    private final RawPage source;

    // Other stuff - the results of the processing
}

class RawPage
{
    // The data you need here

    public ProcessedPage process(...)
}
```

When a class has information which is only *sometimes* valid / needed / relevant, it ends up being quite tricky to work with, especially as the system grows in size. With a more explicit model, you do *potentially* end up with some duplication, but your classes end up with a better defined purpose in life, rather than suffering from multiple personality disorder.

Note that I *haven't* made `ProcessedPage` a subclass of `RawPage` - because I don't imagine you'd normally want to treat a `ProcessedPage` *as* a `RawPage`, potentially reprocessing it. You *may* want to have a common interface that they both implement which doesn't include the `process` method, of course, but that's slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is it depends. If the attributes are not related, can be categorized then it makes sense to split the current class into two.

However if the attributes have generalization - specialization relationship, then you can have one class as base and put rest of the attributes into a different classs which is the extension of the first class

Shash

Answer (score 0):

Are they the exact same attributes? Sometimes you may have attributes in logical data scopes that have the same name but different *contextual* meaning. Is that the case for your scenario? If not then I would say go with one class, unless there is behavior associated with the RawPage that you want to encapsulate differently than that for your ProcessedPage.